# Conn Configuration for AWS Lambda Python RDS Postgres IAM Authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

Recently it was create the possibility to access RDS instances with IAM users and roles. I am confused about how to configure a python connection, since I would not use the database authentication data with psycopg2.

Now I am using like this:

`conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='%s' user='%s' host='%s' password='%s'" % (db_name, db_user, db_host, db_pass))`

I have not idea how to use IAM credentials to connect my lambda function with IAM auth.

Please help.

Comment: Have you get how to have this working ? If yes can you share how you did it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to create an IAM policy and a DB user as described here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html

Then you need to create IAM role for your Lambda function and attach the IAM policy created above to it. Your Lambda function will need to be executed with this role to be able to create a temporary DB password for the DB user.

Finally, you can generate a temporary password for your DB user (created above) within your Lambda using a code snippet like this:

```
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
import boto3

def get_password(rds_hostname, db_user, aws_region=None, url_encoded=True):
    if (not aws_region):
        aws_region = boto3.session.Session().region_name
        if (not aws_region):
            raise Exception("Error: no aws_region given and the default region is not set!")

    rds_port = 5432
    if (":" in rds_hostname):
        split_hostname = rds_hostname.split(":")
        rds_hostname = split_hostname[0]
        rds_port = int(split_hostname[1])

    rds_client = boto3.client("rds")

    password = rds_client.generate_db_auth_token( Region=aws_region,
                                                  DBHostname=rds_hostname,
                                                  Port=rds_port, 
                                                  DBUsername=db_user)
    if url_encoded:
        return quote_plus( password )
    else:
        return password
```

Do not assign the the password to a variable. Get a new password on every run, since the password has limited time validity and your Lambda container might not be recycled before it expires...

Finally, create the DB connection string for whatever python package you use (I would suggest some pure Python implementation, such as pg8000) from your RDS hostname, port, username and the temporary password obtained with the function above (`<user>:<password>@<hostname>:<port>/<db_name>`).

Connecting to the RDS might be a bit tricky. If you don't know how to set up VPC's properly I would suggest you run your Lambda outside of VPC and connect to the RDS over a public IP.

Additionally, you will probably need to enforce SSL connection and possibly include the RDS CA file in your Lambda deployment package. The exact way how to do this depends on what you use to connect (I could only describe how to do this with pymysql and sqlalchemy).

Each of these steps could be described in a tutorial of it's own, but knowing about them should be enough to get you started.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you @grepe! Is that the only way of connecting to RDS using IAM? I thought I would not have to generate temporary passwords to get access.

Comment: @GustavoSooeiro I know of no other way than described above. IAM authentication is just a custom AWS mod to your DB engine that allows to verify that temporary passwords and you use IAM console to manage who/what can generate them. It's still 100x better than managing credentials yourself, but for a simple use case you might want to check out https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/tutorials_basic.html

Comment: I've managed to set up everything. The problem now is that I am getting a token, but if I try to use it I've got no connection. Its a very very long string. Should be this long.

Comment: myinstance.cbgo77fh7r8o.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/?Action=connect&DBUser=db_user&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Date=20181004T194035Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Security-Token=FQoGZXIvYymsvV9GrSj%2F%2Bj0psW6lc6TqAJaODm61OA55X%2BJmMFt962veIVDiFA%2BDnOHe3qFPPG%2BKfnpOOMRXbfeqL8XCtnW1a0bJoaHM89jNj2%2B86bbVO69Y1y%2BaoE6KySGgJI9r29VcphOZIp5bZ7BTlqnwYiKsASuTJfEQ2mgquvsTHMhZVhMdaXNkg8hn7HBj6bf19jCz5qwvj%2FFmvKJXP2d0F&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATY5IZGSJYGHBPLQG%2F20181004%2Fus-east-1%2Frds-db%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=ef813a67a1c7b6b02c7925760be43a290ce7eec16cc4e2f

Comment: Should I extract some info to get the connection with psycopg2 to work?

Comment: @GustavoSooeiro yes, this is your password. it's only valid for 15 minutes (by default), but you should probably not post it online publicly ;) test first from command line... it's a bit tricky, because even if you don't have correct IAM permissions, the command will not return error - it will just return slightly shorter string than what you posted and your DB authentication (next step) will fail. if you make it part of a connection string, make sure you URL encode it (shouldn't be necessary if you use it as a separate argument).

Comment: @GustavoSooeiro actually I think the string yoy posted is URL encoded, but if you use it as a separate password argument it should not be. jist set the url_encoded to False.

Comment: You can just get the region from the environment variable in the Lambda. Also, it HAS to have a region so at no point will `if not` return true